# Snowflake connector .Net connection test Failed Incorrect username and password

Tags: azure, azure-devops, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to build a connector for ADF to snowflake using .Net snowflake data but after the build test got failed due to Incorrect user and password 
I am using a snowflake on azure can any one suggest do I need to add more config in `parameter.json` file Please find the below error.

Already tried without password test scenario.

https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-net/

> error Message:
>    Snowflake.Data.Client.SnowflakeDbException : Incorrect username or password was specified.
>   Stack Trace:
>      at Snowflake.Data.Client.SnowflakeDbConnection.Open() in D:\LululemonResources\VS\snowflake-connector-net-master\snowflake-connector-net-master\Snowflake.Data\Client\SnowflakeDbConnection.cs:line 113
>      at Snowflake.Data.Tests.SFConnectionIT.TestConnectWithDifferentRole() in D:\LululemonResources\VS\snowflake-connector-net-master\snowflake-connector-net-master\Snowflake.Data.Tests\SFConnectionIT.cs:line 214
>   Skipped  TestOktaConnection
>   Skipped  TestSSOConnectionWithUser
>   Skipped  TestSSOConnectionWithWrongUser
>   Failed   TestSwitchDb
>   Error Message:
>    Snowflake.Data.Client.SnowflakeDbException : Incorrect username or password was specified.
>   Stack Trace:
>      at Snowflake.Data.Client.SnowflakeDbConnection.Open() in D:\LululemonResources\VS\snowflake-connector-net-master\snowflake-connector-net-master\Snowflake.Data\Client\SnowflakeDbConnection.cs:line 113
>      at Snowflake.Data.Tests.SFConnectionIT.TestSwitchDb() in D:\LululemonResources\VS\snowflake-connector-net-master\snowflake-connector-net-master\Snowflake.Data.Tests\SFConnectionIT.cs:line 160
>   Failed   TestUnknownConnectionProperty
>   Error Message:
>    Snowflake.Data.Client.SnowflakeDbException : Incorrect username or password was specified.
>   Stack Trace:
>      at Snowflake.Data.Client.SnowflakeDbConnection.Open() in D:\LululemonResources\VS\snowflake-connector-net-master\snowflake-connector-net-master\Snowflake.Data\Client\SnowflakeDbConnection.cs:line 113
>      at Snowflake.Data.Tests.SFConnectionIT.TestUnknownConnectionProperty() in D:\LululemonResources\VS\snowflake-connector-net-master\snowflake-connector-net-master\Snowflake.Data.Tests\SFConnectionIT.cs:line 144
>   Failed   TestSelectStatement
>   Error Message:
>    Snowflake.Data.Client.SnowflakeDbException : Incorrect username or password was specified.
>   Stack Trace:
>      at Snowflake.Data.Client.SnowflakeDbConnection.Open() in D:\LululemonResources\VS\snowflake-connector-net-master\snowflake-connector-net-master\Snowflake.Data\Client\SnowflakeDbConnection.cs:line 113
>      at Snowflake.Data.Tests.SFDbAdaptorIT.TestSelectStatement() in D:\LululemonResources\VS\snowflake-connector-net-master\snowflake-connector-net-master\Snowflake.Data.Tests\SFDbAdaptorIT.cs:line 22
>   Failed   TestCancelExecuteAsync
>   Error Message:
>    Snowflake.Data.Client.SnowflakeDbException : Incorrect username or password was specified.
>   Stack Trace:
>      at Snowflake.Data.Client.SnowflakeDbConnection.Open() in D:\LululemonResources\VS\snowflake-connector-net-master\snowflake-connector-net-master\Snowflake.Data\Client\SnowflakeDbConnection.cs:line 113
>      at Snowflake.Data.Tests.SFDbCommandIT.TestCancelExecuteAsync() in D:\LululemonResources\VS\snowflake-connector-net-master\snowflake-connector-net-master\Snowflake.Data.Tests\SFDbCommandIT.cs:line 402
>   Failed   TestCancelQuery
>   Error Message:
>    Snowflake.Data.Client.SnowflakeDbException : Incorrect username or password was specified.
>   Stack Trace:
>      at Snowflake.Data.Client.SnowflakeDbConnection.Open() in D:\LululemonResources\VS\snowflake-connector-net-master\snowflake-connector-net-master\Snowflake.Data\Client\SnowflakeDbConnection.cs:line 113
>      at Snowflake.Data.Tests.SFDbCommandIT.TestCancelQuery() in D:\LululemonResources\VS\snowflake-connector-net-master\snowflake-connector-net-master\Snowflake.Data.Tests\SFDbCommandIT.cs:line 207
>   Failed   TestDataSourceError
>   Error Message:
>    Snowflake.Data.Client.SnowflakeDbException : Incorrect username or password was specified.
>   Stack Trace:
>      at Snowflake.Data.Client.SnowflakeDbConne

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you check the ACCOUNT and HOST values in your connection string.  Docs here: https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-net/blob/master/README.md

You need to ensure you put whole host url in with rigion (eg australia-east) not just account.snowflakecomputing.com.  E.g. HOST= XXX.australia-east.snowflakecomputing.com

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you reply to a question, try to explain a little bit. In your case,  bringing a live link, at soon as it deads, your question will become useless.

Answer (score 0):

The following github repository might save you a bunch of time.  It is a .NET framework for Azure Data Factory that leverages Azure Functions to execute.  Until Microsoft has a certified source and sink with ADF, this is being leveraged by several Snowflake customers.
https://github.com/jeremiahhansen/snowflake-connector-adf